# AChartEngine 1.1.0 (Android)

Tags: android, graph, achartengine

I used the AChartEngine 1.0.0 plugin to generate a linegraph like this:

[image]

The problem with this is that the y-valyes need to be aligned to the left...
When i looked on the internet i found a solution: using the 1.1.0 plugin instead to have
the method: setYLabelsPadding(10) for the rendering, now i can set the padding correctly but for some reason this happens;

[image]

```
package com.example.driveinstructor.tabactivity.fragments;

import java.util.Random;

import com.example.driveinstructor.R;
import org.achartengine.ChartFactory;
import org.achartengine.GraphicalView;
import org.achartengine.chart.PointStyle;
import org.achartengine.model.XYMultipleSeriesDataset;
import org.achartengine.model.XYSeries;
import org.achartengine.renderer.XYMultipleSeriesRenderer;
import org.achartengine.renderer.XYSeriesRenderer;

import android.app.Fragment;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Paint.Align;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;

public class GraphFragment extends Fragment
{
private GraphicalView mChart;

private XYSeries visitsSeries ;
private XYMultipleSeriesDataset dataset;

private XYSeriesRenderer visitsRenderer;
private XYMultipleSeriesRenderer multiRenderer;

private String[]graphValues = new String[11];//11 want op 0 moet ook een punt staan
private View v;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

     v= inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_graph,container,false);

        // Setting up chart
        setupChart();

        // Start plotting chart
        new ChartTask().execute();

    return v;
}

 private void setupChart(){

        // Creating an  XYSeries for Visits
        visitsSeries = new XYSeries("Unique Visitors");


        // Creating a dataset to hold each series
        dataset = new XYMultipleSeriesDataset();
        // Adding Visits Series to the dataset
        dataset.addSeries(visitsSeries);        


        // Creating XYSeriesRenderer to customize visitsSeries
        visitsRenderer = new XYSeriesRenderer();
        visitsRenderer.setColor(Color.WHITE);
        visitsRenderer.setPointStyle(PointStyle.CIRCLE);
        visitsRenderer.setFillPoints(true);
        visitsRenderer.setLineWidth(2);
        //visitsRenderer.setDisplayChartValues(true);
        visitsRenderer.setColor(Color.parseColor("#FF8800"));//kleur vd lijn


        // Creating a XYMultipleSeriesRenderer to customize the whole chart
        multiRenderer = new XYMultipleSeriesRenderer();

    //  multiRenderer.setChartTitle("Visits Chart");
    //  multiRenderer.setXTitle("Seconds");
    //  multiRenderer.setYTitle("Count");
        multiRenderer.setZoomButtonsVisible(false);

        multiRenderer.setXAxisMin(0);
        multiRenderer.setXAxisMax(10);

        multiRenderer.setYAxisMin(0);
        multiRenderer.setYAxisMax(3000);
        multiRenderer.setYLabels(7);
        multiRenderer.setXLabels(10);
        multiRenderer.setBarSpacing(2);

        multiRenderer.setShowLegend(false);
        multiRenderer.addSeriesRenderer(visitsRenderer);
        multiRenderer.setMargins(new int[] {20,58, 0, 40});  // top, left, bottom, right.
        multiRenderer.setMarginsColor(Color.argb(0x00, 0xff, 0x00, 0x00));

        // Getting a reference to LinearLayout of the MainActivity Layout
        LinearLayout chartContainer = (LinearLayout) v.findViewById(R.id.graph1);


        multiRenderer.setYLabelsPadding(10);
        multiRenderer.setShowGridX(true);
        multiRenderer.setShowGridY(true);

        mChart = (GraphicalView) ChartFactory.getLineChartView(getActivity(), dataset, multiRenderer);


        // Adding the Line Chart to the LinearLayout
        chartContainer.addView(mChart);

    }


    private class ChartTask extends AsyncTask<Void, String, Void>{

        // Generates dummy data in a non-ui thread


        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params)
        {
            int i = 0;
            try{

                do{
                    String [] values = new String[2];
                    Random r = new Random();
                    int visits = r.nextInt(3000);
                    System.out.println("index i= " + String.valueOf(i));
                    System.out.println(String.valueOf(visits));

                    graphValues[0] = Integer.toString(visits); //bijhorende waarde y-as



                    publishProgress(graphValues);                   
                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                    i++;

                    if (i>10)
                    {
                        i=10;
                    }

                    for(int j=i; j>0; j--)
                    {
                    //System.out.println("j" +j);
                    graphValues[j]=graphValues[j-1];

                    }




                }while(i<=20);
            }catch(Exception e){ }
            return null;
        }

        // Plotting generated data in the graph
        @Override
        protected void onProgressUpdate(String... values)
        {

            int a = 0;
            for(String s: values)
            {
                if(s!=null)
                {
        //  System.out.println("test " + s);
            visitsSeries.add(a, Integer.parseInt(values[a]));       
            a++;
                }
                else
                {
                    break;
                }
            }
            mChart.repaint();

            //visitsSeries.add(Integer.parseInt(values[0]), Integer.parseInt(values[1]));
            //mChart.repaint();
        }

    }    


}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to adjust three things (First increase the space on the left side on Y-axis then add extra padding to move the values to the left then use ylabelsAlign property)

```
multiRenderer.setMargins(new int[]{1,2,3,4}); 
//second value corresponds to the space on the left side of Y-axis
 multiRenderer.setYLabelsPadding(someFloatValue);
//Padding will adjust the values to the left side
multiRenderer.setYLabelsAlign();
```